# FIPS_mode_set() code not found in openssl package

Tags: c, openssl, fips

I am new to openssl, and I downloaded openssl-fips-2.0.1 codes from openssl, however, I was not able to trace to the definition of FIPS_mode_set() as stated in the documentation and security policy. I did find, however, fips_set_mode() in fips.c, but they are not referring to the same, am I right?

Where is the definition? 
Please advise me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> FIPS_mode_set() code not found in openssl package

You have to know how to ask...

```
openssl-1.0.1f$ grep -R FIPS_mode_set *
apps/openssl.c:     if (!FIPS_mode_set(1)) {
CHANGES:  *) Functions FIPS_mode_set() and FIPS_mode() which call the underlying
crypto/cpt_err.c:{ERR_FUNC(CRYPTO_F_FIPS_MODE_SET), "FIPS_mode_set"},
crypto/evp/evp_cnf.c:   if (!FIPS_mode() && !FIPS_mode_set(1))
crypto/crypto.h:int FIPS_mode_set(int r);
crypto/o_fips.c:int FIPS_mode_set(int r)
Binary file fips_premain_dso matches
ssl/ssltest.c:      if(!FIPS_mode_set(1))
util/libeay.num:FIPS_mode_set    3253    EXIST::FUNCTION:
openssl-1.0.1f$
```

The declaration is in `crypto/crypto.h` and the definition is in `crypto/o_fips.c`. Here's from `o_fips.c`:

```
int FIPS_mode_set(int r)
    {
    OPENSSL_init();
#ifdef OPENSSL_FIPS
#ifndef FIPS_AUTH_USER_PASS
#define FIPS_AUTH_USER_PASS "Default FIPS Crypto User Password"
#endif
    if (!FIPS_module_mode_set(r, FIPS_AUTH_USER_PASS))
        return 0;
    if (r)
        RAND_set_rand_method(FIPS_rand_get_method());
    else
        RAND_set_rand_method(NULL);
    return 1;
#else
    if (r == 0)
        return 1;
    CRYPTOerr(CRYPTO_F_FIPS_MODE_SET, CRYPTO_R_FIPS_MODE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    return 0;
#endif
    }
```

---

If you were looking for `FIPS_mode_set` to enter into "FIPS mode" with special setup or switch some algorithms, that does not happen at this step.

It happens earlier when linking. What happens under the hood is `fipsld` is you compiler, and it looks for an invocation of `LD`. If `LD` is *not* invoked, then `fipsld` just calls your regular compiler (probably `/usr/bin/gcc`). If it sees an invocation of `LD`, then it does three things.

First, it compiles `fips_premin.c`. Then it calls the real `ld` to perform the final link with all your object file and the `fips_premain.o` it produced. Finally, it calls `incore` to swap in the FIPS Object Module, calculate the signature over the relevant `text` and `data` (relevant means the FIPS code and data), and then embeds the signature in the executable.

The signature is generated with an HMAC, and the key is embedded in the executable. There's nothing special about it, and its constant across all executables throughout the world. Here's the key used: `etaonrishdlcupfm`.

---

If you are not taking special steps when build your executable, then you are probably missing some steps. Here are the steps to use `fipsld` and `incore`:

```
$ export CC=`find /usr/local -name fipsld`
$ echo $CC 
/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld
$ export FIPSLD_CC=`find /usr/bin -name gcc`
$ echo $FIPSLD_CC 
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Now, do a standard `config` and `make`. Sometimes you have to do `config`, then adjust `CC` and `FIPSLD_CC`, and then run `make` because some `config` files choke on the arrangement. Sometimes you have to open a `Makefile` after `config` and change `CC` to `/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld`. There's lots of ways to do it in an effort to work around particular packaging.

---

> I downloaded openssl-fips-2.0.1 codes from openssl, however, I was not able to trace to the definition of FIPS_mode_set()

`openssl-fips-NNN` provides the FIPS validated cryptography *if* you build the FIPS Object Module according to the Security Policy. You can find the [OpenSSL FIPS 1402- Security Policy at here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.pdf).

If all you did was download and build `openssl-fips-NNN`, then you are probably not using FIPS validated cryptography. There's a procedure to follow, and that includes getting a "trusted" copy of the source code. You can download and verify a signature, but you need a FIPS validated signature checker, which creates a chicken-and-the-egg problem because you can't build it from sources. So the practical solution is to order the CD from the OpenSSL Foundation. Its bizarre, but its the truth. See, for example, the [OpenSSL FIPS User Guide](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf) or the [OpenSSL FIPS Security Policy](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.pdf), Appendix B, Controlled Distribution File Fingerprint.

Once you have the FIPS Object Module built and installed, you can build the FIPS Capable version of the library. The FIPS Capable OpenSSL will use the FIPS Object Module, if available. Think of it as a "pluggable" architecture.

The FIPS Capable version of the library is simply `openssl-NNN`, such as `openssl-1.0.1e` and `openssl-1.0.1f`. Its what you know and love.

---

You might also consider something like `ctags` as a source code browser to help you find things and jump around. See [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) on Sourceforge.

Comment: Hi noloader, I wished this answer came earlier. I would have given you the bounty. 
I will mark up your comments to +1 for you. 

btw, how do you set the hmac key. Currently, it is hard coded. Where may we store the key and how may it be read during runtime?

Comment: "how do you set the hmac key..." - I added some more information to the answer.

Comment: +1 for @noloader. Just to confirm, there is no way we can change the verification key, and there is no security issue that it is public?

Comment: "there is no way we can change the verification key..." - you can, but you will need a private label validation because you are modifying the FIPS source code. The OpenSSL Foundation can give you a quote for the cost of the changes.

Comment: Thank you, @noloader. I see you comment on FIPS. I will learn from your comments, and +1 for them, as my way of saying thank you. :)
I am honored by your help. It's very entertaining.

Comment: "...there is no security issue that it is public" - well, this came about because NIST pounded square software into a round hardware hole. If the key was burned into a tamper resistant ROM in a tamper resistant enclosure, then the HMAC key would make more sense. But when NIST developed the software specs, they grafted the hardware specs onto the software. So you encounter these oddities at times.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer header file `crypto.h`. I am able to find its definition there at line 566 as follows:

```
int FIPS_mode_set(int r);
```

[Documentation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_mode_set%28%29) clearly mention that it is in header file `<openssl/crypto.h>`.

So, in your code, include `openssl/crypto.h` to include the definition of this function. If you face other problem, you can browse through questions of OpenSSL that may help you.

Comment: Relativly to the package's root it's protoyped in `include/openssl/crypto.h`

Comment: There is no code in the header for definition, only declaration. There is no code in the documentation for definition, only use example. I am looking for 

int  FIPS_mode_set(int r) {
   :
   :
}

Answer (score 2):

For linkage `FIPS_mode_set()` should be available from `libcrypto` (`*.a` for static linkage and `*.so` for run-time linkage).

`libcrypto.a/.so` comes with your distro's `openssl`'s developer package, or as a result of bulding  `openssl-x.y.z` yourself.

You find the sources for `FIPS_mode_set()` in the sources for `openssl-x.y.z`, in the file `crypto/o_fips.c`.

Comment: The key point here is that it is not in the openssl-fips-2.0.1 , but openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz. Am I right? How are the 2 source different, and how is this being used?

Comment: Yes you are right. @UrsaMajor: you might like to read here http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html and here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide.pdf

Comment: I read the guide, and am confused. I believe you are right, it may be in the other package. I thought I do not require it since I have the *fips*.tar.gz. I got a -1 for the question, it is quite depressing to see how judgemental people are. 

@alk, It states, I can award it in 6 hours time. You deserve the +50 AND +1 for the appropriate answer, I am giving it to you. :)

I am hoping if you can give me more guidance on how to compile and run a fips-test on this.

Comment: Awarded to @alk some seconds ago.

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation migration guide explain that should be used different functions:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/migration_guide.html

Removed FIPS_mode() and FIPS_mode_set()

These functions are legacy APIs that are not applicable to the new provider model. Applications should instead use EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled(3) and EVP_default_properties_enable_fips(3).

I have added this one(I am not sure still that it is good, but hope should be for all versions):

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_MAJOR < 3
    FIPS_mode_set(0);
#else
    EVP_default_properties_enable_fips(nullptr, 0);
#endif
```